# Allow user to upload only one file with Plupload

Tags: plupload

`multi_selection=false` limits user from **selecting** more than one file per once and `max_file_size` limits, how large file can be. But, is there anyway with Plupload to allow user to send only *one file at all*?

I only want to use Plupload as AJAX-uploader and reuse its chunking feature. I'm not interested at all in its ability to upload more than one file at once. I know, that I can block it (limit transfer to just one file) on server side, but this will happen after transmission has been made.

Is there any way to limit upload to just one file on client side, before any actually file transfer occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution, I came up with, is to use [events](http://www.plupload.com/examples/events), write your own code for `QueueChanged` event:

```
QueueChanged: function(up) {
    function(uploader)
    {
        if(uploader.files.length > 1)
        {
            uploader.files.splice(1, uploader.files.length);

            apprise('You can not add more than one file!', {});
        }
    }
}
```

and put this into `init` section of [Plupload Queue widget](http://www.plupload.com/examples/queue) configuration (or bind this particular event with `uploader.bind`, if using simple, [core UI version](http://www.plupload.com/examples/core) of Plupload).